# Opencv-python: Type of input image should be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4! in function fastNlMeansDenoisingColored

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I wrote a simple opencv program, which reduce the noise of images.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('stream/horse.png')

dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)

cv2.imshow(dst)
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
```

[horse.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A89mW.jpg)

When I ran the program it gave an error. Which is...

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Type of input image should be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4!) in fastNlMeansDenoisingColored, file /home/govinda/github_repos/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp, line 176
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/govinda/workspace-python/opencv/src/Smle.py", line 7, in <module>
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)
cv2.error: /home/govinda/github_repos/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:176: error: (-5) Type of input image should be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4! in function fastNlMeansDenoisingColored
```

How should I over come this?

Comment: Your link is a jpeg picture, not png (I guess it was converted). So it's hard to debug what went wrong. I would check `print img.shape` to see if the number of channels is 3 or 4 (also to check if the image was read successfully).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need to convert the image like this:

```
converted_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

A little late to help you, but I hope it helps someone.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions, and I got the following error, error: OpenCV(4.1.1) ..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: Hi, this error happens to me when the image file does not exist or I can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if it's *.png or *.jpg file. Matplotlib also gives you a different outcome. Try the following code:

```
# fastNlMeansDenoisingColored
# Wait for result, takes time to respond
import cv2
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# Do not show graphics window
root.withdraw()

# Load the original color image
origColorImage = cv2.imread(filedialog.askopenfilename(),1)

# Image must have 3 channels
print("Shape of image ", origColorImage.shape)

dest = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(origColorImage,None,10,10,7,21)

cv2.imshow('Original image',origColorImage)
cv2.imshow('fastNlMeansDenoisingColored',dest)
```